# Trouble understanding OpenGL buffer indices

Tags: opengl

I have some OpenGL code that works:

```
... excerpt from shader script
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;\n\
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vert_colour;\n\
layout(location = 2) in uint model_idx;\n\
layout(std430, binding = 4) buffer model_ssbo\n\
...

... excerpt from code
    case GfxBuffer::PositionData:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_handle);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0u, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        break;

    case GfxBuffer::ColourData:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_handle);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1u, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        break;

    case GfxBuffer::ModelIndices:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_handle);
        glVertexAttribIPointer(2u, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, NULL);
        break;

    case GfxBuffer::ModelData:
        glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4u, m_handle);
        break;

    case GfxBuffer::VertexIndices:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_handle);
        break;
```

I want several shaders, some with colour only (this one), one with texture only, and one with colour and texture. To do this I want to shift the ModelIndices buffer index to position 3 to make room for the UV array. Like this:

```
...
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;\n\
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vert_colour;\n\
layout(location = 3) in uint model_idx;\n\
layout(std430, binding = 4) buffer model_ssbo\n\
...

...
    case GfxBuffer::ModelIndices:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_handle);
        glVertexAttribIPointer(3u, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, NULL);
        break;
...
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

I also tried leaving it at index 2 and using `glVertexAttribPointer()` instead, like this:

```
    case GfxBuffer::ModelIndices:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_handle);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2u, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        break;
```

Even though the index remains the same, this doesn't work either.

I thought that the value of `index` in the OpenGL call needed to match the layout location in the shader script, but apparently it isn't that easy. Can anyone please explain how buffer indices work fully so I can get this right reliably.

Comment: *"I thought that the value of index in the OpenGL call needed to match the layout location"* - of course, the attribute index is the binding between an array of generic vertex attribute data and the vertex shader input variable. So the issue has to be some where else in your code. Did you change the index in [**`glEnableVertexAttribArray`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml), too?

Comment: Note, a vertex shader input and storage buffer are different types of resources. The index respectively binding point has to be unique for each type of resource. So its not a conflict to use `layout(location = 0)` for a input and `layout(std430, binding = 0)` for a storage buffer.

Comment: Rabbid, you are a genius. Thankyou so much.
I missed calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`.
Also I read the Khronos information about the storage buffer but didn't understand it. Your explanation is so much better.

I would be really grateful if you put your comments as a proper answer so I can accept it and upvote it.